# The argument type 'MaterialColor' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialStateProperty<Color>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question related with the new ElevatedButtonThemeData widget, basically I want to set the background color for all ElevatedButtons in my app, I'm struggling trying to set it up in the ThemeData definition by doing:

```
      theme: ThemeData(
        ...
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
            style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red)), // Here Im having the error
        ...
        ),
      ),
```

Error:

```
The argument type 'MaterialColor' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialStateProperty<Color?>?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

After reading the documentation I found the way to set the color.

```
  theme: ThemeData(
    ...
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red))), // Here Im having the error
    ...
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: This works perfectly!

Answer (score 31):

Here is a code snippet that shows how I have styled a text button, by using material state properties.

You can see how can you add `different types` of values:

```
TextButton(style: ButtonStyle(
      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(0)),
      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(8),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50))),
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
      shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface),
    ),),
```

I hope this gives you an idea.

To know more about MaterialStateProperty, you can go for this official video:
[MaterialStateProperties | Decoding Flutter](https://youtu.be/CylXr3AF3uU)

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using `ButtonStyle()` try:

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red)
```

Comment: This is a proper answer for a one-time. `.styleFrom()` is handy in flutter!

Answer (score 8):

```
MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red)
```

This returns `MaterialStateProperty<Color?>` data type.

Answer (score 3):

**Before:**

```
backgroundColor: Colors.green,
```

**After:**

```
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

backgroundColor returns the data type of MaterialStateProperty inside the ElevatedButton therefore use `MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red))`
OR

e.g.

```
child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)),
          child: Text('Go Forwards To Screen 1'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
```

Use

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red)
```